# How to split dataframe values and apply a function to the list's contents

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe structured

```
df = DataFrame({
'id':['1', '2'],
'Level 1':['1. text TXT.', '2. Text'],
'Level 2':['1.1.text.textext.', '2.1.Text TXT'],
'Level 3':[NaN, NaN],
'Level 4':['lowercase_text','lowercase_text2']})
```

The goal is to capitalize every value just like you would a normal sentence - only the first letter of the first word needs to be capitalized, while any acronyms remain as they are.

I've tried `df.apply(lambda x: x.str.capitalize())` but this method breaks acronyms and doesn't work correctly with paragraph titles when there is no space between paragraph numbering and the text.
So idea was to split each value over any end of sentence punctuation (while keeping split symbols), remove leading spaces, pick the first character of every element of the list and put it to upper case. Then merge it all back together into cell values with proper spacing.
The difficulty for me is referencing list elements to capitalize them.

The result should looks like:

```
id | Level 1             | Level 2       | Level 3 | Level 4
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1. Text TXT.        | 2. Text       | NaN     | Lowercase_text
2  | 1.1. Text. Textext. | 2.1. Text TXT | NaN     | Lowercase_text2
```

NaNs are actual undefined values to show that they should remain as they are (.str methods turn them into textual 'NaNs').

The original dataframe has more columns, so I would like to apply the code to all of them.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one approach using regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

def func(val):
    if pd.isna(val):
        return val
    return re.sub(r"([0-9.\s])([a-z]+)", lambda x: "{}{}".format(x.group(1), x.group(2).capitalize()), val)

df = pd.DataFrame({
'id':['1', '2'],
'Level 1':['1. text TXT.', '2. Text'],
'Level 2':['1.1.text.textext.', '2.1.Text TXT'],
'Level 3':["NaN", "NaN"]})

df = df.applymap(func)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  id       Level 1            Level 2 Level 3
0  1  1. Text TXT.  1.1.Text.Textext.     NaN
1  2       2. Text       2.1.Text TXT     NaN
```

Comment: @gribna. applies `str.capitalize` on the second captured group...The first captured group is set as it is

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to exclude nans, as they will either give an error or turn into text 'nan' if I change "val" to "str(val)"?

Comment: "ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''", 'occurred at index Level 1'
Regardless, I should be able to fix nans myself.

Comment: Sorry abt that..`if pd.isna(val):`

Comment: With the if edit I get the same error. Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes. it does...are you trying the exact same snippet as above?

Comment: Yes, it was the same but I decided just to fillna() and not figure out why it wasn't working.
However, the function doesn't seem to be working on values like 'Level 4':['lowercase_text', 'lowercase_text2'].  I should've made it part of input data.